# Validate text input with throttling (or rateLimit'ing) while typing

Tags: knockout.js

I have gone down a rabbit hole for what I thought would be fairly trivial.  The goal is to validate user input, as they type, with a throttle.

Based on what I've read I need to use a `purecomputed` observable and extend that with a `rateLimit`.  Or something like this:

```
this.validateSmsValue = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        let hasPlaceholder = self.smsMsg().indexOf('[link_placeholder]');
        self.smsMsgIsValid(hasPlaceholder !== undefined);
    })
     .extend({
       rateLimit: { method: "notifyWhenChangesStop", timeout: 500 }
     });
```

In the HTML, I'm attempting to bind with:

```
<input id="smsMsgEdit"type="text" data-bind="textInput: smsMsg, event: {keypress: validateSmsValue}" maxlength="160" >
```

In it's current form I'm getting the error `Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.`

I'm continuing to read documentation and search out examples but my Google-fu is failing me.

What is the correct KnockoutJS way of validating user input on a text field once they stop typing for 1/2 second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a subscription to an observable rather than to use a computed function. No need for the separate keypress event binding either.

```js
function viewModel(){
  var self = this;
  
  self.myValue = ko.observable().extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: 500, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" } });
  
  //validate
  self.myValue.subscribe(function(newValue){
    console.log(!isNaN(newValue));
  });
  
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

Value is a number?
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: myValue" />
```

Comment: Ah! This solves more problems for me than just this one...I started thinking I needed to find some way to emit an event (angular style) to accomplish this in knockout - it's so simple! Thanks!